# Match each group separately followed by a dash

Tags: regex, powershell

I have some markdown files where I've been using two spaces as tabs instead of four. For correct markdown syntax it should be four spaces, so I am trying to do a find and replace in each of the files.

I can match the double spaces, but when I attempt to only match the groups preceding a dash, it doesn't match what I need.

```
# List in Markdown
- List Item
  - List Item
    - List Item
      - List Item
  - List Item
    - List Item- List Item
```

If I use `/ {2}/mg`, it matches each group of 2 spaces separately.
https://regex101.com/r/v1qF15/1

But I only want to replace the spaces that precede a dash. The problem I'm having is that when I add grouping and the dash, all instances of double spaces before a dash is one match instead of individual matches.

```
/(?: {2})+(?=-)/mg
```

https://regex101.com/r/VqvrP8/1

Match 1: The set of 2 spaces on line 1
Match 2: The set of 4 spaces on line 2
Match 3: The set of 6 spaces on line 3

But what I really want is:
Match 1: The set of 2 spaces on line 1
Match 2: The first set of 2 spaces on line 2
Match 3: The second set of 2 spaces on line 2
Match 4: The first set of 2 spaces on line 3

I think I'm doing something wrong with my positive look behind or my grouping, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: To be honest regex is not the right tool for the job. You should be parsing the files as YAML and then serializing them back out as standardized YAML. Here's a module you can install to (de)serializeYAML from PowerShell (I haven't used it so can't comment on its effectiveness): https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/powershell-yaml

Comment: So, something like `$var -replace '^(?:(\s{2}-))','  $1'`?

Comment: Looks like I had the correct regex, but I was just over complicating the replacement.  @mklement0 helped me put everything together.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your (multi-line) input string is stored in variable `$str`:

```bash
$str -replace '(?: {2})+(?=-)', '$&$&'
```

In your simple case, it's sufficient to know the *combined* length of the two-space multiples that matched, allowing you to in effect *double* them simply by referring to what was matched (`$&`) *twice* in the substitution expression.

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm. I think I was trying to overthink the solution.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @MDG.